# Increasing quota on google elevation api

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, quota, elevation, google-elevation-api

I am sending from my application queries to the Google elevation api, like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=false.
I have reached my daily quota after 2500 requests and google states in their documentation that I can buy extra quota.
However I was unable to find where I could buy this quota increase. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy Google professional API starts at £8K per year.. !!

Comment: Wow, really ? However they claim that Google Api for businesses gives a limit of 100k queries per day with possible increase to 1M, and Google Api for private gives a limit of 2.5k with possible increase to 25k. So there seemingly is an Api for private without buying the profesionnal one. Or did I get it wrong &

Answer (score 0):

You can now pay for your usage. Check out the plans page here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/